# StructureMap.config automatic setters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have 2 plugins in my application (ASP.NET MVC 4). Both of them use same interface.

For example

```
MyApp.Plugins.Abstract.IMainPlugin
```

with required Execute method

Now, I have plugins named `MyApp.Plugins.ClockPlugin` and `MyApp.Plugins.TimePlugin`. ClockPlugin class has property `Code` inside it (`public int Code {get; set;}`) which has to be injected by StructureMap using StructureMap.config file (how?).

So far I have in my StructureMap.config:

```
<StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">
  <DefaultInstance
    PluginType="MyApp.Plugins.Abstract.IMainPlugin, MyApp.Domain"
    PluggedType="MyApp.Plugins.TimePlugin, MyApp.Plugins" />
</StructureMap>
```

How to add `ClockPlugin`in this default instance and automatic setter for `Code`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.structuremap.net/XmlConfiguration.htm):

> Primitive constructor or setter arguments are just defined as attributes in the Xml node

For example:

```
<StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">
  <DefaultInstance
    PluginType="StructureMap.Testing.Widget.IWidget,StructureMap.Testing.Widget"
    PluggedType="StructureMap.Testing.Widget.ColorWidget,StructureMap.Testing.Widget"
    Scope="Singleton"
    Color="Red" />
</StructureMap>
```

Should set the `Color` property to `Red`.

Comment: yes, but what about adding 2 implementations to one interface?